# How to set dynamic properties of processor(Nifi) using java front end

Tags: apache-nifi

how to set properties file of processor of apache nifi from Jsp        front-end using java?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be great if you could provide what you have tried so far and explain your question more detailed.

Comment: I have java web application with jsp servlet and want to connect this application with apache nifi .
Is this possible to configure properties of Nifi processor from Java Jsp .
Plesae suggest me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds pretty unnecessary since you have the NiFi UI. If you want to do so anyway, you have [NiFi's Rest API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) so you can configure and even deploy new DataFlows with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I want to configure Nifi Processor settings and properties from my jsp page . Is this possible from NiFi's Rest API ?

Comment: @KumariMeenu of course. It is exposed so you can do such thing. You can even open your browser's network tab and see how it is done with NiFi's UI.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment ... Could you please give some example or steps for How to call nifi restAPI from java and add processor to nifi UI from java end .

Comment: Just track the requests NiFi makes and read the documentation. This should be all you need to know how to use it.